# Como enviar login e senha para este sistema de autenticação..?(login automático)

Tags: php, auth

vocês muito provavelmente já conhecem e/ou viram aquele antigo sistema de autenticação do apache (htpasswd | imagem abaixo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pois bem, eu preciso criar um código que envie o login e senha para o formulário e entre direto na página. Sem a necessidade de ter que digitar tudo manualmente.

Eu sei que é possível fazer isso em formulários html utilizando o CURL, mas nesse ai eu não faço a mínima ideia.

Obs: Eu quero realizar **login** automático, não criar essa janela.
Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço.

======================== Exemplo utilizando o CURL e um formulário HTML:

```html
<?php
  $curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.sitecomsistemaauth.com/index.php');
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'meulogin=abc&senha=123');
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1;

            // Variável que armazena o HTML renderizado após o login;
            $sendPost = curl_exec ($curl);

            // REGEX PARA PEGAR STRINGS DA PÁGINA
            $pattern = '@(.*)@';
            $target = $sendPost;
            $matches = array();

            $finalContent = $normalMode($pattern,$target,$matches);

            // Retorna todos os resultados encontrado;
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($finalContent,$matches);

            curl_close ($curl);
?>
```

**Isso eu consigo fazer em formulário HTML, mas como fazer em um "formulário" http basic authentication?.**

Comment: Seria algo assim que vc quer?
http:///usuario:senha@dominio:porta?

Comment: Olá, obrigado por responder. Então, eu já havia tentado este método só que tem algumas desvantagens, por exemplo: Não funciona no IE e se eu usar dentro do php teria que ser algo como "header("Location: http://usuario:senha@dominiio")" e neste caso ele iria direto pra página e o código php finalizaria. Eu quero algo que dê pra trabalhar a página depois entende? tipo armazenar a página que vem depois do login em uma variável e utilizar expressões regulares para manipular o conteúdo.

Comment: Então eu não entendi sua pergunta. Você poderia editar para ficar mais clara.

Comment: Editei. Na verdade a dúvida é bem simples, talvez eu realmente esteja me expressando incorretamente. Se eu enviar os parâmetros via URL como no exemplo, a janela vai aparecer pedindo login e senha do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Tem um link: (http://solvedstack.com/questions/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl) mas eu não entendi como funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer passar as credenciais é só fazer assim:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$usuario:$senha");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

Para utilizar:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.site.com/index.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "login:senha");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Caso continuar persistindo o problema, troque

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

Por

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
```

Se for [`Digest access authentication`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
```

### Segunda solução

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:text/html',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("login:senha") // <---
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.site.com/index.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26641/discussion-on-answer-by-maicon-carraro-como-enviar-login-e-senha-para-este-siste)

Comment: @utluiz ele não tem pontos suficientes

Comment: Sem problemas. Essa é uma mensagem automática do sistema quando Movi as mensagens.